error: cannot find symbol import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.Barcode;
i am having this issue. I had to check the official site for libraries import typo to make sure it same but still getting the error. What i am missing?
enter image description here
enter image description here
here gradle look >
enter image description here
And here Barcode Activity.java >
package com.carplayandroidautoconnect.textscannerx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory; // Added import
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.DocumentsProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanner;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScannerOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class BarcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_CODE = 4000;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button selectImageButton = findViewById(R.id.selectImageButton);

        selectImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_CODE);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_CODE && data != null) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            if (imageUri != null) {
                processImage(imageUri);
            } else {
                textView.setText("No image selected.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void processImage(Uri imageUri) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to open InputStream.");
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to decode bitmap.");
            }
            InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0);

            BarcodeScannerOptions options = new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
                    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE, Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_128)
                    .build();

            BarcodeScanner scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options);

            scanner.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(barcodes -> {
                        StringBuilder resultText = new StringBuilder();
                        for (Barcode barcode : barcodes) {
                            resultText.append("Raw Value: ").append(barcode.getRawValue()).append("\n");
                        }
                        textView.setText(resultText.toString());
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        Log.e("BarcodeActivity", "Barcode scanning failed", e);
                        textView.setText("Failed to recognize barcode.");
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("BarcodeActivity", "Error reading file", e);
            textView.setText("Failed to process image.");
        }
    }
}

I am trying to run the code to see how it look as a app on mobile but it won't letting me do due to error.

I know its late but after having the same problem, i accidentally tried
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.common.Barcode;
took me 2 hours to figure it out....
